# Continuous Function Takes Minimum And Maximum

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I've got a question on a proof given in Charles Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis.

**Theorem.** A continuous function $f$ defined on an interval $[a,b]$ takes on absolute minimum and absolute maximum values.

*Proof.* Let $M = \sup{(f(t))}$ for $t \in [a,b]$. In the book we've already proven that $M$ exists. Consider the set $$ X = \{x \in [a,b]: \sup{(V_x)} < M \} $$
where $V_x$ is the set of values of $f(t)$ as $t$ varies on $[a,x]$.

Case 1. $f(a)=M$. Trivial.
Case 2. $f(a) < M$. Then $X \neq \emptyset$, so there exists a least upper bound of $X$, say $c$. If $f(c) < M$, we choose $\varepsilon >0$ with $\varepsilon < M - f(c)$. By continuity at $c$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $|t-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(t)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$. Thus, $\sup{V_c}<M$.

(By continuity, we can easily show $c=b$ and finish the proof.)

I'm kind of confused in case 2. He says "Thus, $\sup{V_c}<M$" after introducing some continuity argument.

However, doesn't it immediately follow from $c = \sup{X}$ that $\sup{V_t} < M$ for $t \in [a,c)$ and by assumption $f(c) < M$?

Am I mistaken here? The author makes it seem like the inequality follows from the continuity argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto \sup V_x$ is (clearly) non-decreasing, hence $c=\sup X$ indeed implies $t\in X$ for all $t\in[a,c)$ and thus also $\sup V_t<M$ for all $t\in[a,c)$. Without using continuity of $f$ at $c$, this cannot tell us anything about $f(c)$ because $f(c)$ does not enter into any $\sup V_t$ when $t<c$.

In fact, consider $a=0$, $b=2$, a non-continuous $f(x)=\begin{cases}x&0\le x<1\\0&1\le x\le 2\end{cases}$. Then $M=1$, $X=[0,1)$, $c=1$, $f(c)<M$,  and $\sup V_c=M$.

Comment: The counterexample made it immediately clear (stupid that I didn't look for one myself heh), thanks a lot!